# Angular Bootstrap with tabs and carousels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have a series of Angular Bootstrap tabs (each containing a carousel), my HTML looks something like this:

```
<tabs>
    <pane>
        <carousel>
            <slide>
                <div>Some content (Pane 1, Slide 1)</div>
            </slide>
            <slide>
                <div>Additional content (Pane 1, Slide 2)</div>
            </slide>
        </carousel>
    </pane>
    <pane>
        <carousel>
            <slide>
                <div>Some more content (Pane 2, Slide 1)</div>
            </slide>
            <slide>
                <div>Even more content (Pane 2, Slide 2)</div>
            </slide>
        </carousel>
    </pane>
</tabs>
```

I need to be able to tell when a tab is clicked, which slide is active. I then get the heading of the slide and display it on another div.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? Dont know what you mean by Angular Bootstrap. Is that a mix of AngularJS and Bootstrap?

Comment: I can work to put one together... Here is the link to Angular Bootstrap: http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to modify the Controller `TabsController` in the `ui-bootstrap-0.2.0.js`

Comment: How would your make the TabsController aware of the child carousels? When one is active (which you know) by the selectPane(pane) function call, and I can modify.  The issue is getting access to the currently selected slide in the pane's carousel.

Also, I'm working on a plunkr... just simplifying things

Comment: I finally got around to setting up a [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sCWv7s)

I edited ui-bootstrap-0.2.0.js to take out all the bootstrap stuff I'm not using, and so line 47 emits what the new selected heading is. The issue I'm trying to solve: How to get the selected slide's heading when a tab is selected. as tschiela said, I should edit the TabsController, but I'm not quite sure how to get that working. I have played around in selectePane() but can't figure out how to access the pane

The heading init's with an initial heading, which I can live with for now.

Comment: I found a solution for now, which allows me to correctly identify the currently active slide. The tab controller keeps an array of all the slides, and can calculate the correct slide index to use.